# htaccess send all requests to index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How to write a .htaccess that will send all requests to index.php but not when the request is defined inside an exception list.

I now use this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) index.php [QSA,L]
```

It works for the first part. But now I have to make PHP code to request my images and css files. How can I change the htaccess code to create exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `RewriteCond` and match against `$1`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !\.css$
RewriteCond $1 !^some/folder
# etc..
RewriteRule (.*) index.php [QSA,L]
```

So the first condition excludes anything ending with `.css`, the second excludes anything that starts with `/some/folder`

Comment: do u mind taking a look at my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77879577/7543162)?